# Universal app iPad to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created an Universal app. I have designed the app for iPad. But it doesn't work in iPhone. Will it work automatically or do i have to create all nibs separately for iPhone.

Comment: definetlty you need to create separate xibs

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will not work automatically, if your design is for iPad only it will not work on the iPhone.

You will have to create separate XIBs for the iPad and iPhone, you can use the same viewController (.h and .m file) but seperate XIBx. Just add the device modifier to the file: `MyViewController.xib` and `MyViewController~iphone.xib` or `MyViewController~ipad.xib`.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it will not work for iPhone by itself. But its not difficult to add the support for iPhone.

Create a new StoryBoard for iPhone. Then open your iPad StoryBoard, the one you already created. Select all and copy. And then open iPhone StoryBoard and paste it in. All the controls and everything you have done in the iPad StoryBoard will be added to your iPhone StoryBoard.

After that you can do modifications in iPhone StoryBoard like remove or add some new controls etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no mention of storyboards in the question, so why should he use storyboards?